# How convert type of List<System.IO.FileInfo> to List<string>?

Tags: c#, regex, directory

I need to convert this type of List to List of string:

```
var fileName = (new DirectoryInfo(filePath)).GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a.Name, "^[^*]*" + logSelected + ".jpg$")).ToList();
```

somebody know how is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var fileName = (new DirectoryInfo(filePath))
.GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a.Name, "^[^*]*" + logSelected + ".jpg$"))
.Select(a => a.Name)
.ToList();
```

Or change `a.Name` in the Select method for the property you need.

Answer (score 0):

try adding  `.Select(fi => fi.Name)`

```
List<string> fileNames = (new DirectoryInfo(filePath)).GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a.Name, "^[^*]*" + logSelected + ".jpg$"))
            .Select(fi => fi.Name)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileName = new DirectoryInfo(filePath)
                   .GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                   .Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a.Name, "^[^*]*" + logSelected + ".jpg$"))
                   .Select(x => x.Name)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            var fileName = (new DirectoryInfo(filePath)).GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a.Name, "^[^]" + logSelected + ".jpg$"))
            .Select(fi=>fi.FullName)
            .ToList();
```